# is there any way to drag clock hands(i.e hour hand and minute hand) seprately?

Tags: flutter

I have a analog clock which shows current time. I have wrapped the clock dial with flutter Gestures. after wrapping the clock dial with I get the co-ordinates of the clock by dragging inside the clock dial. I can able drag clock hour and minute hand but the problem is both the hour and minute hand rotates same time while dragging. I would like to move hour and minute hand separately.
My code looks like this

```
class RedTimerDial extends StatefulWidget {
//timer dial parameters, constructors,... goes here
 @override
_RedTimerDialState createState() => _RedTimerDialState();
}
class _RedTimerDialState extends State<RedTimerDial> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new DialTurnGestureDetector(
      // here goes dial container code
      //I call the clock from here(as a child)
   new ClockHands(rotationPercent: _rotationPercent(),),
  );
 }
 }
```

My DialTurnGestureDetector looks like this

```
class DialTurnGestureDetector extends StatefulWidget {
   // here goes gesuture detecotrs parameters and constructors
 @override
  _DialTurnGestureDetectorState createState() => _DialTurnGestureDetectorState();
}
class _DialTurnGestureDetectorState extends State<DialTurnGestureDetector> {
  PolarCoord startDragCoord;
  Duration startDragTime;

_onRadialDragStart(PolarCoord coord){
startDragCoord = coord;
startDragTime = widget.currentTime;

}
_onRadialDragUpdate(PolarCoord coord){
/*
final coordination = new SnackBar(content: new Text('Radial Drag Coord: $coord'));
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(coordination);
print('Radial Drag Coord: $coord'); */

if (startDragCoord != null){
  final angleDiff = coord.angle - startDragCoord.angle;
  final anglePercent = angleDiff / (2*pi);
  final timeDiffInSeconds = (anglePercent * widget.maxTime.inSeconds).round();
 // final newTime = new Duration(seconds: widget.currentTime.inSeconds + timeDiffInSeconds);
  final newTime = new Duration(seconds: startDragTime.inSeconds + timeDiffInSeconds);
  print('New Time: ${newTime.inMinutes}');
  widget.onTimeSelected(newTime);
 }

}
 _onRadialDragEnd(){

 }


 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return new RadialDragGestureDetector(
  onRadialDragStart: _onRadialDragStart,
  onRadialDragUpdate: _onRadialDragUpdate,
  onRadialDragEnd: _onRadialDragEnd,
  child:widget.child,
 );
}
}
```

My clock hands class looks like this

```
class ClockHands extends StatefulWidget {
// here goes some declarations and constructors
  @override
_ClockHandsState createState() => _ClockHandsState();   
}
class _ClockHandsState extends State<ClockHands> {
  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new AspectRatio(
    // here goes some clock hands container code
   child: new Stack(
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: <Widget>[
              new CustomPaint( painter: new HourHandPainter(
                  rotationPercent: widget.rotationPercent,
                 // rotationPercent: 0.00,
                  hours: dateTime.hour, minutes: dateTime.minute),
              ),
              new CustomPaint(painter: new MinuteHandPainter(
                  rotationPercent: widget.rotationPercent,
                  minutes: dateTime.minute, seconds: dateTime.second),
              ),
              new CustomPaint(painter: new SecondHandPainter(seconds: dateTime.second),
              ),
            ]
        )    
 );
}
}
```

Comment: You can 1) look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svxUUz5mi9s) for a step by step process to implement an egg timer; 2) import the [fluttery package](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttery) to simply use the code; or 3) manually copy the [gesture detector](https://github.com/matthew-carroll/fluttery/blob/master/lib/src/radial_drag_gesture_detector.dart) from the package to your project.

Comment: @Edman : Thanks for sharing me the video link. it helped me a lot to understand the flutter programming. But still I am struggling to what have to do. I am able to move the clock hand manually by changing the rotation Percent(as per the video explanation). I am not able to pass dynamic value to the Rotation Percent.

Comment: hi, is there any update on this?

Comment: @WisnuWijokangko :No updates so far. I am not able to achieve what I wanted to do with the clock hands. If you have any idea please let me know